# Driving a load on negative rail with a positive signal

Tags: level-shifting

[image]

I want to turn the LED on when the 5V pulse is high. I expect a simple circuit consisting of two or three bipolar or MOSFET transistors similar to the erroneous one in the image above. I don't want to add and ICs if possible.

Note 1: I'm not powering the LED from VCC, because I have already loaded the VCC rail heavily; I would be draining too much current if I add the LED too.
Note 2: VCC and VEE are referenced to the GND.
Note 3: The LED is actually a LED inside an optocoupler. I need a circuit which responses in 1\$\mu\$s at most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one idea:

[image: schematic]

When the input is at 0V, Q1 is saturated, pulling the base of Q2 to almost +5V, so
Q2 is off, and D1 gets only leakage current.

When the input is at 5V, Q1 is off, allowing the base of Q2 to fall to -0.6V, turning Q2 on and illuminating the LED D1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: -

[image]

To drive current into the base of the BJT (and light the LED) the input voltage (into R2) has to overcome the forward volt drop of the 18V zener and the Vbe of the BJT (approximately 18.7V in total). If the input voltage were at 0V there would be only tiny leakage currents thru the zener and the LED wouldn't light.

Comment: The requirement is for 5V pulses and -15V negative rail. I don't think this will work.

Comment: @alexan_e oops I read -5V not -15v. I shall amend.

Comment: The circuit will always be on, no matter if the control voltage is 5V or 0V, you need a zener of 16V or so (zener voltage higher that the negative rail voltage).

Comment: @alexan_e I eventually took a course on learning how to add numbers and after two failed attempts I hopefully got it right!!